# why can't i pass two different comparators to one template function?

Tags: c++, templates, comparator, c2664

I'm wracking my brain here for several hours, but I still don't understand why I'm getting an error when I'm trying to run this code.
After some time I managed to narrow it down to the expression:

```
pastryPrice()
```

which causes the problem - as you can see, I'm trying to build numerous comparators for one template function of sorting

```
    struct dialingAreaComp{
    inline bool operator()(const Deliver *d1, const Deliver *d2)const {
        return d1->getDialingArea() < d2->getDialingArea();
    }
};
struct pastryPrice {
    inline bool operator()(const Pastry *p1, const Pastry *p2)const {
        return p1->getPrice() < p2->getPrice();
    }
};
template<class T>
void sortCollection(T& collection)
{
    if ( typeid (collection) == typeid(vector <Deliver*>))
    {
        sort(collection.begin(), collection.end(), dialingAreaComp());
        printCollection(collection);
    }
    else if (typeid (collection) == typeid(vector <Pastry*>))
    {
        sort(collection.begin(), collection.end(), pastryPrice());
        printCollection(collection);
    }
    else { cout << "WRONG!"; }
}
```

I'm getting five errors, all the same:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   C2664   'bool Bakery::pastryPrice::operator ()(const Pastry *,const Pastry *) const': cannot convert argument 1 from 'Deliver *' to 'const Pastry *'    Bakery  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xutility 809

And one more:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   C2056   illegal expression  Bakery  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xutility 809

When I take off the expression I wrote above, the code works **just fine** - why can't I pass two different comparators to one template function?

Now:

> C2264 is a Compiler Error that occurs when one tries to pass a function a parameter of an incompatible type.

But the Deliver function works and when I took off the Deliver comparator the Pastry compiled as well... so what is the incompatible type?

Comment: That's because template are evaluated at compile time, whereas your `if` statement is evaluated at runtime. So always one of the function calls doesn't match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get an error because the templated function is evaluated at compile time, and one of the function calls will never match. Instead of the template use simple function overloads:

```
void sortCollection(vector <Deliver*>& collection)
{
    sort(collection.begin(), collection.end(), dialingAreaComp());
    printCollection(collection);
}

void sortCollection(vector <Pastry*>& collection)
{
    sort(collection.begin(), collection.end(), pastryPrice());
    printCollection(collection);
}
```

Comment: Awesome! thank you - i would have never guess that the incom

Comment: *i would have never guess that's the incompatible part... I tried to avoid from creatin/invoking several sort functions.

Comment: @prowler _"I tried to avoid from creatin/invoking several sort functions."_ There wouldn't be much gain from that.

Comment: Not on the resources aspect - but I need to present the code to my lecturer, showing her that i understand the code and the way OOP works in C++. So... i thought it would be nice to create one template function for sorting.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is both branches are compiled regardless of which one is taken.

I would approach this differently.

```
template<class A, class B>
struct overload_t:A,B{
  using A::operator();
  using B::operator();
  overload_t(A a, B b):A(std::move(a)), B(std::move(b)){}
};
template<class A, class B>
overload_t<A,B> overload( A a, B b ){
  return {std::move(a),std::move(b)};
}
```

This lets us overload two function objects or lambdas.  (Perfect forwarding could be added, as can varargs..., but I kept it simple).

Now we simply:

```
auto comp=overload(dialingAreaComp{}, pastryPrice{});
using std::begin; using std::end;
std::sort( begin(collection), end(collection), comp );
```

and the compiler chooses the correct comparison function for us.  Also flat array support while I was in there.

And stop using `using namespace std;`.

---

What the above code does is fuze your two function object tyoes into one.  The `using A::operator()` and `using B::operator()` moves both `()` into the same class and tells C++ to pick between them when invoked using the usual method call overloading rules.  The rest of the code is glue to deduce the types being overloaded and move-construct them.

`sort` calls `()` with objects of the compile-time determined type based on the type of the container.  Overload resolution (within `sort` at the point of call) then picks the right body to compare at compile time.

Thus technique can be extended with support for more than 2 overloads, function pointers, and forwarding references.  In C++17 some work can be done to have the overload type deduce its parent types, removing the need for the factory function.

Comment: This may be a bit overkill for OP. But it looks so beautiful. With some tinkering this could probably be made into not only accepting 2 overloads.

Comment: @hayt yes that is easy.  I just kept it short and sweet.

Comment: @Yakk this is nice! Can you say why the need for the constructor `overload_t(A a, B b):A(std::move(a)), B(std::move(b)){}`? Without it in the make-like function you can  just `return {};`.

Comment: @Yakk yeah I saw the mention only after I post the comment and could not edit it anymore.... i was distracted by the code ;)

Comment: @vsoftco you have to give the constructor the a and b values. `{}` does give it nothing.

Comment: @Hayt That's why I was asking why the need for the ctor in the first place. Just remove the ctor altogether from `struct overload_t`. Wouldn't it work? After all, you are just deducing the types for `A` and `B` and using their `operator()(...)`.

Comment: @vsoft not all lambdas or function objects are stateless.  In making this simple, I shaved off function pointer support, `...` vararg overload count (and binary tree inheritance), and perfect forwarding.  I did not shave that off.  In C++17 the ctor could be omitted, but I would want to use class template deduction and I think that is worth having a manual ctor.

Comment: @hayt I did edit that `...` in at some point.  Also, while I do get the idea of exposing beginners to beginner techniques, I think something concise and simple like this is worth considering.  New C++ programmers do not have to make all the mistakes we did, the language has evolved.  ;)